# How to hash a row reliably and efficiently in BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

I would like to hash rows to use as a way to determine whether the content of the row has changed over time, but I am not sure of what's the best way to create a hash of the row reliably (without data loss) and efficiently.

My current solution:

```
SELECT FARM_FINGERPRINT(TO_JSON_STRING(table)), *
FROM project.dataset.table
```

Which to me seems:

1. Inefficient - Conversion `TO_JSON_STRING` is pretty heavy handed
2. Potentially unreliable - Is there possible data loss for more complex types (DATETIME, TIMESTAMP, TIME, STRUCT) when converting to JSON?

I know that [BigQuery provides a snapshot backup system](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/table-snapshots-intro) for tables, so maybe there exist a more efficient way used by this service?

I am not opting for BigQuery snapshots because I need to query all snapshot of the table in a single query, which does not seem possible with that service.

Comment: Instead of using snapshots, you can store the result of your FARM_FINGERPRINT per row so you can use it to compare with future checks of your data. With regards to your question about inefficiency and reliability, I can't seem to find anything related to those using BigQuery.

Comment: That I will definitely do. It will be much simpler than recomputing the hash of each record in the history everytime. Thanks for the suggestion :)

Answer (score 2):

Posting comment as an answer from the conversation with @PhilippeHebert. Instead of using snapshots you can store the result of your FARM_FINGERPRINT per row so you can use it to compare with future checks of your data.